# Best way to extend a module in zend framework 2

Tags: module, zend-framework2

What is best way to extend zend framework 2 modules.
For example I want to change register page view in zfcuser , I cloned zfcuser module from vendor to modules folder and changed view files but Zend Framework 2 uses vendor folder one, If I delete zfcuser folder in vendor it works ok but two modules at same time uses vendor version

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to clone the module. You can just create a zfc-user/user folder in your own module's view folder. And then place your own register.phtml in that folder. Just make sure that ZfcUser is included before your own custom module and then your own custom view should be loaded.

Edit: this is a link to the official docs on this topic: [ZfcUser custom view scripts](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/wiki/How-to-override-built-in-view-scripts)

Comment: I know that , But I think it's against software engineering to have thos edited files in another modules folder

Comment: Actually it's better from that point of view, because you are re-using all the basic zfc-user functionality and just override what you want to override in your own custom module. That way you can painlessly update zfc-user in the future when updates are available. Cloning the module and making changes to the core would actually be a bad thing from a software engineering point of view.

Comment: I just want extended files in cloned folder not whole files

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do then. Are you only trying to override views or also other types of classes?

Comment: Just overriding views

Comment: @bigboss So how you want to extends Views (which is practically html file with some needed php code embedded). Approach of ZF2 is justified for views. If you want extend some Library class of Module, Your approach can be justifiable but for views what are other options ?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to override template files just override the **`module.config.php`** in your Modul directory.

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        'zfcuser' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
```

Within your view directory add a folder called **`zfc-user`** and add a **`register.phtml`** file. Within that template file feel free to change whatever you want, just keep in mind that you still have to keep the form action as it is.

Comment: you mean edit zfcuser in vendor folder or in modules folder ?